# Arrow Dictionary over list arrays

Tags: apache-arrow

I have a list arrays of string that I would like to dictionary encode using Arrow in Go and Java

```
["a", ["b", "c"], "b", "c", "d"]
```

Ideally where the dictionary would be done on the individual string values.

I tried to define a type using

```
arrow.DictionaryType{
   IndexType: arrow.PrimitiveTypes.Uint32,
   ValueType: arrow.ListOf(arrow.BinaryTypes.String),
}
```

but that yield the error

```
panic: arrow/array: unsupported builder for value type of *arrow.DictionaryType
```

Any idea what are my options ?

I am thinking doing an extension type and build the dictionary and listOf(String) myself,
but if there is standard way to do this, even better.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a work around for this? Could you elaborate on the extension type solution? I've just been manually storing integers, and storing the dictionary in metadata, which is very kludgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not super confident this is correct, or exactly what you are asking for. But if there's someone here who knows more, please chime in, since I'd also like to do this!

If you have a nested list of strings which need to be stored. For example:

```
[
 ["a"], 
 ["b", "c"],
 ["b"],
 ["c"],
 ["d"],
]
```

I think this can be stored in array by setting the type to:

```golang
arrow.ListOf(&arrow.DictionaryType{
        IndexType: &arrow.Int64Type{},
        ValueType: &arrow.StringType{},
        Ordered:   false,
    })
```

Full code example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/apache/arrow/go/v15/arrow"
    "github.com/apache/arrow/go/v15/arrow/array"
    "github.com/apache/arrow/go/v15/arrow/memory"
)

func main() {
    type_ := arrow.ListOf(&arrow.DictionaryType{
        IndexType: &arrow.Int64Type{},
        ValueType: &arrow.StringType{},
        Ordered:   false,
    })

    fields := []arrow.Field{{
        Name:     "foo",
        Type:     type_,
        Nullable: false,
    }}

    schema := arrow.NewSchema(fields, nil)

    builder := array.NewRecordBuilder(memory.DefaultAllocator, schema)
    builder.Retain()
    defer builder.Release()

    vals := [][]string{
        {"a", "b", "c"},
        {"x", "b"},
        {"x", "y", "z"},
    }

    b := builder.Field(0).(array.VarLenListLikeBuilder)
    db := b.ValueBuilder().(*array.BinaryDictionaryBuilder)

    for i := range vals {
        val := vals[i]
        b.AppendWithSize(true, len(val))
        for j := range val {
            err := db.AppendString(val[j])
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }

    rec := builder.NewRecord()
    rec.Retain()
    defer rec.Release()

    t := array.NewTableFromRecords(schema, []arrow.Record{rec})
    t.Retain()

    fmt.Println(t.String())

    defer t.Release()
}
```